# Finding and/or counting the amount of black pixels in an image using NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to figure out the differences between the coordinates I give points in a plot vs the coordinates those points have when I save the image and open it in a NumPy array.

In order to understand the transform needed, I first tackle the question:

> How can I actually know the amount pixel mark of matplotlib isn't a few pixels wide when I work with the image?

Therefore I'm trying to create 2 pixel sized markers in a simple plot and see if I can receive 2 values when inquiring it from NumPy.

So far this is the code I tried:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

#creating figure and subplot

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(4,2))

ax = fig.add_subplot()

#These lines are for 'cleaning' the lines that might interfer with the black pixel count
ax.set_position([0, 0, 1, 1])
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)

#creating of the two mentioned pixels
ax.plot([1, 2],[0.4,0.4], marker='o',ms=72./fig.dpi, mew=0, 
        color='black', linestyle="", lw=0)
ax.set_xlim(0,8)
ax.set_ylim(0,1)

plt.show()
fig.savefig('plot.png', dpi=fig.dpi)
pix=np.array(Image.open('plot.png'))
black_points=np.all(pix==(0,0,0,0),axis=-1)
print(pix.shape)
sought = [0,0,0,255]
black  = np.count_nonzero(np.all(pix==sought,axis=-1))
print(black)
```

Currently, the count returns 0 black pixels and I fail to see which part of the code malfunctions.

Comment: I have done this method for finding black or white pixels in picture. One thing that you should care about is that, some pixels look black, but they are not completely black, for example (0,1,0), and some other numbers. The reason is you see some are black but they are not completely black. You should define a range of numbers when identifying pixels.((0,0,0)). Try to set a breakpoint and see what numbers you see in RGB.

Comment: Oh ok! will try and update! thanks for the tip.